# What am I missing in my JUNIT test?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I have the following test code for a class:

```
/**
 * Test Class
 */
public class GeneratorTestTest {
    private Generator generator;
    private static BufferedImage testImage;
    private BufferedImage rotatedImageTestResult;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        generator = new Generator(null, 0);

        File inputFile = new File("src/test/resource/picture.jpg");

        testImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
    }

    /**
     * Test method
     */
    @Test
    public void testRotateImageRotateImage() {
        //Line 39
        rotatedImageTestResult = generator.rotateImage(testImage, 0);
        assertTrue(imageEquals(testImage, rotatedImageTestResult));
    }
```

I am get a `NullPointerException` on the Test method when I try to run it. How can I pass the Junit test?

Here is a full log of the Exception:

> line 39 is "rotatedImageTestResult = generator.rotateImage(testImage, 0);

Comment: You also need to include the stack trace from the Exception, so that we can see *where* the exception is happening.

Comment: If you can include the stack trace usually it will include multiple files that caused the failure.  Since the nullpointer exception is probably happening in the "rotateImage" method we'd probably need the line numbers that mention the Generator file.

Comment: your setUp probably hasn't run yet. You need to have it marked as static.

Comment: setUp should not be static: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html

Answer (score 1):

```
rotatedImageTestResult = generator.rotateImage(testImage, 0);
```

On this line of code either "generator" is null or some helper object in your generator is null so the "rotateImage" method itself is throwing the null pointer exception.

Comment: Or more likely the OP is wrong about which line is 39.